# What does "-y" flag do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, apt-get

```
sudo apt-get -y install python-pip
```

I was trying to install a package from a tutorial and cam across this line of code. I could not figure what is the function of '-y' flag? What does '-y' flag do in the above line of code?

Comment: [explainshell.com](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=sudo+apt-get+-y+install+python-pip) automatically explains what flags do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Automatic yes to prompts; assume "yes" as answer to all prompts and
           run non-interactively. If an undesirable situation, such as
           changing a held package, trying to install a unauthenticated
           package or removing an essential package occurs then apt-get will abort.

Answer (score 2):

By specifying -y flag while installing packages, installer wont ask you for a prompt. Try without -y flag and run the same command and you will better understand.

Answer (score 1):

The option -y (yes) allows to confirm automatically installation of your package.
For more information about this aoption, you can read the manual by using the command "man apt-get"